# Stirling's formula for $|\Gamma(s)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

I have seen Stirling's formula often stated as

$$\Gamma(s) = \left(\frac{2\pi}{s}\right)^{1/2}\left(\frac{s}{e}\right)^s(1 + O(|s|^{-1}))$$
with the implied constant absolute for $\Re s > 0$ (I think this can be made larger, though it isn't relevant here). However, how don't the $s^{-1/2}$ and $s^s$ that occur make it ambiguous since one has to specify a branch?

Comment: Since $\Gamma(t)$ is real and positive for $t \in (0,+\infty)$, it's the branch that is real and positive on $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: $\Gamma(s) - \left(\frac{2\pi}{s}\right)^{1/2}\left(\frac{s}{e}\right)^s$ is analytic on $\Re(s) > 0$ so what Daniel said extends there.